# How should I refer to svg symbols collected into a single svg file?

Tags: html, svg

I have an svg symbol file, here's a snippet.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="oval" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
        <title>oval</title>
        <path ... />
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="rectangle" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
        <title>rectangle</title>
        <path ... />
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="star" viewBox="0 0 55.867 55.867">
        <title>star</title>
        <path ... />
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

What I have right now is

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/icons1.svg"></object>

<svg class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="#size"></use>
</svg>
```

My stylesheet entry

```
svg.icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  color: black;
}
```

The result is no image. If i select across the web page, there's a vastly oversized block (~350 x 150 px) where the image should be, but no image.

How do I refer to, say, `rectangle` from the external file, in the html where it would be used?

Comment: 300 x 150 means the style is not being picked up. How are you linking the stylesheet to the markup?

Answer (score 1):

The `<object>` tag is not needed. All it does is give you a blank area. Insterad, link to the file *and* the  symbol in it:

```
<svg class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="images/icons1.svg#size"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the symbol like so: `<svg><use xlink:href="#rectangle"></use></svg>`

Comment: That's what I thought, what I did. Styled black on white, it's not showing.

Comment: Recreate your issue as a jsfiddle or codepen to illustrate the problem

Comment: Is the SVG embedded in the html document?

Comment: I jsut added the `object` entry. Thanks.